# Determine the cdf of a function of a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose $X$ is a continuous random variable with distribution function $F_{X}$. I want to find $F_{Y}$ where $Y$ is given by $Y=X^2$. The following is my answer, but I feel like there's something wrong like do I need to discuss the value of $X$?

$g$ is a strictly increasing function for $X\geq 0$ and a strictly decreasing function for $X\leq 0$, where $g(X)=X^2=Y$. When $X\geq 0$, we have
\begin{align*}
F_{Y}(y)=\mathbb {P}(Y\leq y)=\mathbb {P}(X^2\leq y)=\mathbb {P}(X\leq \sqrt{y})=F_{X}(\sqrt {y})
\end{align*}
When $X\leq 0$, we have
\begin{align*}
F_{Y}(y)=\mathbb {P}(Y\leq y)=\mathbb {P}(X^2\leq y)=\mathbb {P}(X\geq -\sqrt{y})=1-F_{X}(-\sqrt {y})
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't write these two cases separately since the (random) value of $X$ is not given to you. Only $y$ is given. However, you can write

$$\left\{X^2 \leq y\right\} = \left\{-\sqrt{y} \leq X \leq \sqrt{y}\right\},$$

whence

$$F_Y\left(y\right) = F_X\left(\sqrt{y}\right) - F_X\left(-\sqrt{y}\right).$$